# Default width of iOS 7 views

Tags: ios, uiview, size

When I add a UIViewController to a storyboard in the latest xCode its view is defaults to 600x600 in size. This means centred items appear off to the right and the view extends off the bottom of the screen. Why is this?

Many thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Xcode 6 the interface builder works with AutoLayout. So you need to set constraints to your views to be in the right place. See here how thats works: [Click me](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

But you also can disable the size class to work in the exact ViewController like this:

[image: turn this off]

If you turn size classes off you see an window like this:

[image: window]

Just select the size class you want (iPhone for example) and you can work like you want it. 
But I would recommend to work with AutoLayout due to the fact that there are a lot of different device types (iPhone 4(S), iPhone 5(S), iPad).

Comment: Thanks, will look into auto layout. Very helpful answer.